# Know if filesystem is not mounted on VM

Tags: qemu, mount, kvm, drive

I'm running a Windows 10 VM (with Qemu-KVM) where I mount a 'fake' NTFS drive (a file I created) from the host. I have no problem mounting it and adding files from the VM, but have no way to figure if the file is still used by Windows when trying to mount it on the host to retrieve the files.

When mounting it on the host when it's already used by the VM, mount gives me the following warning :

```
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
The file system wasn't safely closed on Windows. Fixing.
```

However, I couldn't find in the sources how it does to figure this. Does anyone know a way to programmatically know if the drive is still mounted on Windows (such as a flag in the file or by using a tool) ?

I could send a notification to the host via the network when the VM user ejects the device but would prefer a cleaner way.

Comment: VM software use *virtual* drives as a rule, ie special files,  not real drives. In *all* of them, you have to unmount the volume from the VM, not just the OS,  if you want to write to it. Most VM software allows some volumes to appear as removable drives, which is how virtual floppies and USB drives work. It's `qemu` that should know if the drive is ejected or not

Comment: In any case *why* do all that instead of eg *sharing* a folder?

Comment: I'm not using NFS for ergonomy, I want the drive to appear as a USB device inside the VM. I do not want to write on the drive when it's still mounted on Windows, just looking for a way to be sure it was correctly unmounted on the guest before writing on it from the host.

Comment: Hotplugging USB *devices* is something that you configure. If you want to eject the device, you do so from the *guest*. Removable drives in Windows have writ-back caching disable to avoid data loss even if someone just pulls the USB drive out. Did you re-enable it perhaps? In any case this has nothing to do with programming. You should post your question to `unix.stackexchange.com` or `serverfault.com`